# Can i Readline data inside cmd telnet session using VBS?

Tags: cmd, vbscript

Can i extract the **uptime** from the output of a telnet session in cmd using VBS ?

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEF16.png)

```
        Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        objShell.Run "telnet 192.168.1.1"
        Wscript.Sleep(2000)
        objShell.SendKeys("admin~")
        Wscript.Sleep(1000)
        objShell.SendKeys("wan adsl perfdata~")
        Wscript.Sleep(500)
```

Comment: You have to use StdIn and StdOut of WshScriptExec Object. See docs http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe

Comment: i have tried those already but i think they work only with cmd commands like "ipconfig" and "dir" , can you help me with a code to try ?

Comment: Not VBScript, but you may be interested to read that you can use PowerShell to perform 'telnet'. https://www.techtutsonline.com/powershell-alternative-telnet-command/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to send and receive Telnet commands from VBScript. You need to have Python installed on your machine for it to work.

```
Const PythonTelnetCode = "import telnetlib, sys; telnetlib.Telnet(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2]).interact()"
Dim WshShell : Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set PythonTelnet = WshShell.Exec("python.exe -c """+PythonTelnetCode+""" "+IPAddress+" "+CStr(Port)+"")

PythonTelnet.Stdin.WriteLine "My command to Telnet"
TextFromTelnet = PythonTelnet.Stdout.ReadLine
```